# Unable to load VLC plugin in ExtJS panel on IE

Tags: extjs4, vlc

I've noticed that VLC plugin does not appear on IE (8 & 9) when embedded in an ExtJS(4.0.7) panel. The panel brings up the plugin in Firefox. Here's what I've done:

```
if(Ext.isIE) {
    vlc = "<div id='player' align='center'><object classid='clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' version='VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2' id='vlc' name='vlc' style='width: 300px; height: 300px;'><param name='loop' value='false' /><param name='autoplay' value='false' /><param name='toolbar' value='false' /></object></div>";
} else {
    vlc = "<div id='player' align='center'><embed type='application/x-vlc-plugin' pluginspage='http://www.videolan.org' version='VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2' id='vlc' autoplay='no' loop='no' controls='no' style='width: 300px; height: 300px;'></embed></div>";
}

var vlcPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    id: 'vlcPanel'
    ,itemId: 'vlcPanel'
    ,frame: true
    ,bodyPadding: 5
    ,border: true
    ,html: vlc
});
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or insight to resolve this. I have to play a live UDP stream of the form udp://@225.1.1.1:31319. Are there any alternative plugins to VLC to play UDP streams ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed fbvlc and the plugin appeared on IE, but it's still failing with vanilla VLC instatllation.